Showing directly that $C_u(M)$ is separable iff $C_b(\overline M)$ is separable.
Let $M$ be a metric space and let $\overline M$ be its completion.  $C_u(M)$  denotes the Banach space of bounded uniformly continuous functions on $M$  and $C_b(\overline M)$ denotes the Banach space of bounded continuous functions on $\overline M$.
It is known that

$C_u(M)$ is separable if and only if $M$ is totally bounded.

and that

$C_b(\overline M)$ is separable if and only if $\overline M$ is compact.

Since $\overline M$ is compact if and only if $M$ is totally bounded, we see that

$C_u(M)$ is separable if and only if $C_b(\overline M)$ is separable.

Can we prove the above in a more "direct" way?
Notice that each $f \in C_u(M)$ can be uniquely extended to a function $\hat f \in C_u(\overline M) $ such that $\|f\|_\infty = \|\hat f \|_\infty$. So $C_u(M) \simeq C_u(\overline M)$ isometrically.
One direction is trivial: If $C_b(\overline M)$ is separable then so is $C_u(\overline M) \subset C_b(\overline M)$.
The converse seems more difficult. How can one deduce separability of $C_b(\overline M)$ by the separability of $C_u (\overline M)$? Note that $C_u(\overline M)$ is not dense in $C_b(\overline M)$.
